# Yahoo API Call Signature Invalid

Tags: json, api, profile, yahoo, signature

Here is my URL code

```
$url = "http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/{$access_token_array['xoauth_yahoo_guid']}/profile?format=json&realm=yahooapis.com&oauth_consumer_key={$this->Ckey}&oauth_nonce={$this->nonce}&oauth_timestamp={$this->ctime}&oauth_token=".urlencode($access_token_array['oauth_token'])."&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature={$this->Csecret}%26{$_SESSION['yahoo_oauth_token_secret']}";
```

here Csecret is consumer secret provide at signup and $_SESSION['yahoo_oauth_token_secret'] is basically token secret ['oauth_token_secret'] received by https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token...

Now when i am calling above url, it say

```
{"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem=\"signature_invalid\", realm=\"yahooapis.com\""}}
```

i have tried combination of consumer secret %26 token secret, failed
consumer secret only also fail
token secret only also goes to failure...

Where i am making a mistake here...

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Keep `oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT` then try it with consumer secret only (%26 added to the end of consumer secret). `oauth_token_secret` you will get as response from the api service you are requesting.

Regards